# showing uncaught error :cannot call method openDatabase in cordova project

Tags: javascript

When I am running this code .it shows a error ..Uncaught Error:cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined in cordova project .deviceready has not fired after five seconds

```
   var db;
 dbcreated="false";

function onDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
db=window.SQLitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'Registration.db'});
 db.transaction(populateDB,errorCB, populateDB_success);
 var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
 var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
 var Dob = document.getElementById("Dob").value;
 var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
alert("device ready");
 }
function populateDB(tx) {

 var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration ( "
   + "firstName TEXT NOT NULL, " + "lastName TEXT NOT NULL, "
   + "age INTEGER, " + "Dob TEXT NOT NULL, "
   + "password TEXT NOT NULL)";
 tx.executeSql(sql);
 var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
 var lname =  document.getElementById("lastname").value;
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
 var uname =document.getElementById("Dob").value;
 var pwrd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Registration (firstname,lastname,age,Dob,password) VALUES ('"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"' , "+ age+", '"+ Dob +"','"+ pwrd +"' )");
 alert("data inserted");
}

function errorCB(tx,error) {

 alert("database error:"+ error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
 dbCreated = true;

 // where you want to move
 alert("Successfully inserted");
  window.location="file:///android_asset/www/login.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here and risking the obvious but is would seem from the exception that `window.SQLitePlugin` is null indicating that the SQLitePlugin is not loaded, set or initialized.  Are you missing the plugin or not initializing it?